# Sphinx Using SPH_MATCH_ANY Ignores SetFieldWeights and SetSortMode

Tags: search, sphinx

Hey guys, im trying to order my results in the way I want via sphinx 0.99, but its not working.

Im currently using this

```
$cl->SetMatchMode ( SPH_MATCH_ANY );
$cl->SetRankingMode ( SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 );
$cl->SetFieldWeights ( array ( "item_title"=>100,"item_publish_date"=>99 ) );
$cl->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED  , "@weight DESC,item_publish_date DESC" );
$cl->SetLimits(0, 330);
```

Which pulls up all the results, but it ignores the item_publish_date value completely.

If i used SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN isntead of SPH_MATCH_ANY, it does show the results in the order I want, but then it limits the results too much, as similar items will be completely ignored, thats why I need to use SPH_MATCH_ANY to show the most results.

So my question is, how can i factor in item_publish_date using SPH_MATCH_ANY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `item_publish_date` is not a text field, so you don't need to use it in `SetFieldWeights` method, because it's mean nothing. Second, `SPH_MATCH_ANY` ranker compute weight using additionally count of matching words, not only matches. Thats why you need to make some tests and watch for `weight` parameter in different searches.

Here is something to read about [weighting in Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting)